# How to display custom content inline with author name and date in wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress

I need to display custom content inline with author name and date in wordpress post. How can I do this?

```
function display_count() {
   global $post;
   return "Character Count =".strlen( wp_strip_all_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content)));
}

add_filter('get_the_date', 'display_count');
```

Comment: Share your best try here

Comment: You may try [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223988/how-to-display-date-time-author-in-pages)

Comment: I am creating my own plugin from where I need to append text to date and author name. Which filter or action hook will work? I tried get_the_date()

Comment: you must share your code if you want help. Plz edit your question with the piece of code you are struggling with...

Comment: function display_count() {
    global $post;

    return "Character Count =".strlen( wp_strip_all_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content)));

}

add_filter('get_the_date', 'display_count' );

Comment: @gael  I have added the code.

Comment: I need to display character count of post inline with date and author name of post.